# Replace null by blank in select * statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table which has 100 columns. I want to write `select * from table` and null column values should be replaced with blank. I don't want to include 100 columns in
my select statement and write:

```
 select
   isnull(col1,''), 
   isnull(col2,''),
   ...
   isnull(col100,'') 
 from table
```

Comment: You can only do this by generating [dynamic SQL](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/) and executing it. You might also want to add `AS col1`, `AS col2` etc.

Comment: Why do you want to do that in the first place? Why not let the *client code* format values as it sees fit?

Comment: Are every single one of your columns a `varchar` then? `ISNULL({numerical expression},'')` isn't going to return `''` if the expression has the value `NULL`. And @PanagiotisKanavos hits the nail on the head with his comment.

Comment: You should always include the columns in your SQL anyway, because otherwise your code breaks immediately when someone adds a new column, or if for whatever reason in some other environment the columns are in a different order.

Comment: 100 columns probably means this query is meant for reporting or data export. All reporting, export tools and applications can easily handle nulls either directly (eg an option in the export tool) or indirectly, eg with a format string during data binding.

Answer (score 3):

Check this out :

```
DECLARE @TableName  VARCHAR(MAX)='ASC_LOT_TBL'
DECLARE @SchemaName VARCHAR(MAX)='dbo'
DECLARE @ColumnList VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @ColumnList= ISNULL(@ColumnList+',','')+
    CASE WHEN  DATA_TYPE LIKE '%char' THEN 'ISNULL('+COLUMN_NAME+','''') AS '+COLUMN_NAME
         WHEN  DATA_TYPE = 'int' THEN 'ISNULL('+COLUMN_NAME+',''0'') AS '+COLUMN_NAME
    ELSE COLUMN_NAME END
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME=@TableName
AND TABLE_SCHEMA=@SchemaName
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION

SELECT  'SELECT '+@ColumnList+' FROM ' +@SchemaName+'.'+@TableName
```

Comment: to get data (not string query) change last select to EXEC ('SELECT '+@ColumnList+' FROM ' +@SchemaName+'.'+@TableName)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can go over all the suggestion above on SQL/script level, or change your design on your table to not allow NULL and with a default value to '' (In MSSQL, it will be ('')).

[image]

This way, when a new entry is inserted, that column will store the data/value '', not NULL. 
And in this case, you can select * from table with "blank" in  return instead of NULL.

You need to choose from script or table design, one way or another.

Answer (score 0):

[X/Y problem apart](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), to answer your specific question :

To write the query you can use a **regular expression search & replace** in your editor to avoid editing each line a hundred time.

Just *select all the concerned lines* with the columns names after the `SELECT`,

```
col1,
col2,
col3,
...
```

Open search and replace (Ctrl + H) for `(\S+),` and replace by `ISNULL($1, ''),`, with the regular expression mode activated in your favorite editor, and apply the replacement to the selection only.

Illustration in SSMS :

[image: Search and replace regex in SSMS]

It works for instance in Visual Studio, in SQL Server Management Studio, in Notepad++, etc...

(provided there is no space in your column names, otherwise please leave a comment to specify how your column names are, and we can work out a quick solution)

The last line need to be edited manually, but you saved 99 editions anyway ;).

You should also be able to create a view, and then do `SELECT` on your view, this would reduce the need to write this only once (but not tested, and not sure if there could be performance issue in your usecase)